# Type requires name=value pair construction: Donation__c

Tags: apex, custom-object

I have a custom object

```
     @AuraEnabled 
   public static List<Donation__c> onLoad(string recordId){  
   List<Donation__c> donList = new List<Donation__c>();
     Contact con = [select id, Name, (select id, Name, Email1__c from  Donations__r) from Contact where id=:recordId];  
     for(Contact c: con.Donations__r){  
       donList.add(new Donation__c(c,false)); 

   }   
    return donList;  
   }
```

but in this line:

```
 donList.add(new Donation__c(c,false));
```

Compile Error:

> Type requires name=value pair construction: Donation__c

Any advice? Thanx

Comment: What is it you expect this constructor to do? What is the `Donation__c` supposed to do with the `Contact` record, or with this `Boolean`?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you are trying to accomplish is to return all child records for the specified `Contact.Id`. Just query on and return `Donation__c` records directly. If your lookup field has an API Name of `Contact__c`, your entire method body would look like:

```
return [SELECT Name, Email1__c FROM Donation__c WHERE Contact__c = :recordId];
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error is telling you that you're not using the correct syntax to create an instance of a custom object record. You need to explicitly call out a field that you want to set. So something like the below:

```
donList.add(new Donation__c(Contact__c = c.Id , My_Boolean_Field__c = false));
```

However, Adrian Larson's answer is a better example of how to do what it seems you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas.